# canvas.toDataURL not work IOS (It work chrome,ie,android... )

Tags: javascript

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL(); 

console.log(data );
```

chrome,android.... result

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlsA
```

IOS result

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGAAAAAAABBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAA...
```

Why are they different?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009400/todataurl-of-webgl-canvas-returning-transparent-image-in-ios-only

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152652/ios-html5-canvas-todataurl/26160598